# How <c:forEach> work on ajax call?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, el

I have a scenario where i have a SelectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu  value="#{bean.names}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.templChangeListner}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select an Equipment type">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-------Select Names------"
     itemValue="${null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.fetchnames()}" var="spec" 
     itemLabel="#{spec.specName}" itemValue="#{spec.specificationId}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="outputPanel"
    immediate="true" execute="@this"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

On `valueChange` i have to `render` a panel which have

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="outputPanel">

    <c:forEach items="#{ban.genericFeaturesList}"
     var="genFeatVar" varStatus="genericIndex">
  ...............
  ...............
  ...............
  <!--Lots of logic to render component --> 
   </c:forEach>
```

My question is that when `valueChange` will happen and `outputPanel` will render again

1. `genericFeaturesList` will contain new updated data ?
2. Component tree will be build again ?

As i saw when i am adding redirect in `valueChangeListener`  method then things working properly in UI and when i am removing redirect value in UI not rendering properly.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("PageName")
```

Answer (score 0):

JSF can be easily rendered and produce runtime HTML DOM object If we use JSF component instead of `<c:forEach...>`

```
<h:panelGroup id="outputPanel" rendered="#{not empty ban.genericFeaturesList}">
    <ui:repeat value="#{ban.genericFeaturesList}" var="instance">
......
......
......
    </ui:repeat>
<h:panelGroup>
```

... Try this. Good luck!!!

Comment: Are you sure  `<ui:repeat/>`  is a JSF Component ? And it will regenerate the tree on run time?

Comment: Whilst indeed a component, the <ui:repeat> itself does not produce any HTML. So your statement is wrong.

Comment: What is the length of the list. If you print a message, is it coming in panel group?